# Textbox with search icon placement

Tags: css

I am not very good at CSS, the textbox has been aligned to right, I tried putting the search icon into the textbox, it just can't go in. Here are the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#textbox-search{overflow:auto;}

#textbox-search input.searchkeyword {
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     border:1px solid #8e8e8e;
     background-color:#f5f5f5;
     height:16px;
     padding:-4px;
     padding-left:-48px;
     color:#4a4a4a;
     float:right;
 }

#textbox-search input.button{
    border:0;
    padding:4px;
    margint:0 0 0 600px;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    background:transparent url('images/search.png') center center  no-repeat;
    float:right;

}
</style>

<form id="textbox-search">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="" />
<input type="text" class="searchkeyword" />
</form>
```

UPDATE : [image]

Comment: the background image is set for the button, isn't it?

Comment: yes, all have been setup properly, by default it is on the left, once I change it to right, it seems malfunction =_=

Comment: From you question, I thought you wanted the icon (background image?) in the textbox not the submit button.

Comment: Is this question about positioning or about a background image not displaying? A clear description would help.

Comment: submit button = the search icon image, the search icon image must be inside the textbox. Understand? My english kinda fail, sorry if you don't understand.

Comment: updated with picture, the problem I am facing.

Comment: I would recommend not putting the submit button (with image) inside or on top of the textbox.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply achieve this using `background` property like this

```
input{  
    background: url("http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1389/g5_system/32/toolbar_find.png") top right no-repeat;
    height:30px;
    padding-right:30px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zUzgU/)

You can change Height and padding value as per your image dimension.

Comment: The search icon is a button which should be positioned inside the textbox, not a background image.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this

```
.searchkeyword {
  width: 100%; /*textbox width*/
  float: none;
  background: url(your_image.png);
  background-size: 20px 20px;/*background icon size*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 8px 10px; /*place where you wnat*/
  display: block;
  text-indent: 20px; /*help to indent your text on textfield*/
}
```