# How to add a search icon in my search input

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code to display a search input as follow:-

```
<form method="GET" action="@Url.Action("Search", "Home")">
<input   placeholder="Search" name="searchTerm2" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Home")" type="text"  />
</form>
```

but how i can modify my search input to have an imag such as :-

[image]

I tried setting a background image but this image will be at the beginning of the input field instead of being at the end , and users will be able to write over the background image ? any advice please ?

Thanks

Comment: I have given the answer of similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000283/textbox-with-search-icon-placement/16000586#16000586

Comment: thnaks for the link, but how can i make force the imag to redirect to a search function when the user click on it ?

Comment: I have posted an answer for clickable button. Please see it and let me know if it make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a class to this input like `.search`, and then with CSS:

```
.search{
    background:url(path/to/search-icon.png) no-repeat right center;
    padding-right: size-of-your-icon-in-pixels;
}
```

Also, you could remove the search icon when user focused input:

```
.search{
    background:url(path/to/search-icon.png) no-repeat right center;
}

.search:focus{
    background:none;
}
```

Comment: but is there a way to make this imag click able , so that when the user type his search criteria and then click on the imag ,, to redirect the user to the search result page ? as currently the imag will not be clickable, and the user have to click on the "Enter" button to execute the search ? ?

Comment: @johnG the best approach to this would be use a ```button``` with the icon on it, and then "stick" it to the end of the input, maybe some style to make them look like one single input would be nice too